# HTTP proxy detecting HTTP client disconnection

Tags: c++, http, networking, keep-alive, poco-libraries

I'm new to HTTP, and developing an applicative proxy.
I want to avoid defining timeouts for operations, and instead rely on the the client to close the connection.
I'm wondering if this is possible?

here's a very dumbed down pseudo code

```
void handle_request(Request http_request, Response http_response)
{
   string modified_request = parse(http_request);
   response_from_server = remote_server->send_request(modified_request);
   while(true) {
     if(response_from_server ->wait_for_data(1000 /* milliseconds */)) {
       http_response->write_data(response_from_server->read_data());
       continue;
     }

     if(!http_response.check_if_the_client_connection_to_me_is_still_active()) // how to do this?
         return;
     }
   }
}
```

another way to ask this is:

1. in an HTTP proxy, can I use the timeouts from the remote cilent and the remote server without adding yet another timeout?
2. how do I detect that either the remote server or remote client have timed-out?

incidentally, I'm developing in C++ using Poco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *cannot write* a serious TCP application without using timeouts. They are in some cases the only way you can detect a dropped connection while reading. TCP provides the following ways to detect a dropped connection:

1. The various EOS conditions on read.
2. 'Connection reset' on write or occasionally read.
3. Read timeout.

That's it. There aren't any more.

You should also enable TCP keepalive from your end, but that only kicks in after two hours.

Comment: Wrong. 1. Relying on `RST` + keep-alive is usually enough to detect dead connections. 2. TCP keep-alive timeout is configurable. 3. Timeout doesn't necessarily indicate a problem, this is a matter of the protocol. OTOH one *may* want a timeout to get rid of idle client (the one that maintains a TCP connection, but doesn't respond on the applicative level).

Comment: @valdo (1) TCP keepalive only operates after two hours by default. A proxy needs to be a lot more responsive to dead connections than that. (2) TCP timeout is indeed configurable, *for the entire system,* i.e. every connection, *if you have the necessary privileges.* This is neither desirable nor in most cases practical.

Comment: At least in Windows, using winsock2 API, one may (and should) configure TCP keep-alive per socket. `WSAIoctl` with flag=`SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS`

Comment: i'm not sure this answers the question. read the pseudo code again.

Comment: @valdo 'Usually enough' isn't nearly strong enough to make what I wrote wrong. I have seen cases where an entire server went down and the read at the client blocked for several days because no RST was received. A read timeout would have detected it in seconds with 100% reliability.

Comment: @AviadRozenhek The pseudo-code is unimplementable. The only way you can detect a disconnection is by reading or writing. Blocking mode reads can block forever unless you use a read timeout.

Comment: @EJP what about using select() or poll() to check the state of the connection?

Comment: @AviadRozenhek Using select() or poll() works fine provided you use a timeout.